# How can I query the enable status of a plugin in nose?

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py

I'm currently trying to see if a nose plugin is enabled from within my test harness. The specific thing I'm trying to do is propagate the enable status of the coverage module to subprocess executions. Essentially when --with-coverage is used, I want to execute the subprocesses under the coverage tool directly (or propagate a flag down).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those cases where you need to work around nose.  See [Measuring subprocesses](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/subprocess.html) in the coverage documentation for ways to ensure that subprocesses automatically invoke coverage.